# counting different things in same column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

So I have a column in a table that has 4 regions (NA, EMEA, LATAM, APAC). I'm trying to create one query that counts how many times each region shows up. Right now, my query is

```
USE CompDataCenters 
GO
SELECT COUNT(Region) AS NA
FROM [CompDataCenters All In]
WHERE Region = 'NA'
```

But that only shows me the total for the number of times 'NA' shows up. How do I write a query that shows the counts of all the regions? Or do I have to write them all separately?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Region, COUNT(Region)
FROM [CompDataCenters All In]
GROUP BY Region;
```

Comment: Wow I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It is very Simple.

```
SELECT COUNT(Region) AS NA
FROM [CompDataCenters All In]
WHERE Region = 'NA'
Group by Region
```